# How to Send Array as an Argument using Post Method in Sencha 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I am developing one application in my service I have to send an array as aparam,

```
 Ext.Ajax.request({
     method: 'POST',
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
     type: 'json',
     url: 'http:/....',
     disableCaching: false,
     headers: {
         'Accept': 'application/json',
             'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     },

     jsonData: {
         FirstName: local_fname_array2,

     },


     success: function (response) {
         console.log(response);
     }

 });
```

And in service.... like this

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "/Check1")]
 int Psngr(string[] FirstName);
```

Service definition:

```
public static int Psngr(string[] FirstName) {
    List < Psgr > psgr = new List < Psgr > ();
    var getVal = from s in FirstName select s;
    int count = getVal.Count();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ToString());
    con.Open();

    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_InsertCheck1", con)) {
        int result;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName[i]);
            using(var Da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))

            using(var Ds = new DataSet()) {
                Da.Fill(Ds);
                result = Convert.ToInt16(Ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Result"].ToString());

            }


        }

        return 1;
    }
}
```

But I got error....

**The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter: FirstName. The InnerException message was 'Expecting state 'Element'. Encountered 'Text' with name ', namespace '. '. Please see InnerException for more details.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should encode your array data before send to server, sth like this:

Ext.encode(the_array)

Answer (score 0):

You have to decode the Array

```
jsonData: {
  trvlrTitle:Ext.decode(local_prefix_array)
}
```

Later you have to send:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url:'http://aa.com,
    method:'POST',
    disableCaching: false,
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    jsonData: {
        trvlrTitle:Ext.decode(local_prefix_array)
    }
});
```